# JSON Decode Error when trying to convert string

Tags: python, json, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape the data from a script tag in json format as seen below with BeautifulSoup but I encounter an `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` error which implies that the variable is empty. What am I missing here?

```
#PYTHON:
    a = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json")
    a = str(a)
    print (a)
    
    data = dict()
    script_dict = json.loads(a.replace("'",'"'))
    print (script_dict)
    data["author"] = script_dict["author"] 
    data["embed_url"] = script_dict["embedUrl"]
    data["duration"] = ":".join(re.findall(r"\d\d",script_dict["duration"]))
    data["upload_date"] = re.findall(r"\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}",script_dict["uploadDate"])[0]
    data["accurate_views"] = int(script_dict["interactionStatistic"][0]["userInteractionCount"].replace(",",""))
```

Data to be scraped:

```
  <script type="application/ld+json">
            {
                "@context": "http://schema.org/",
                "@type": "DATA",
                "name": "Klaus ;",
                "embedUrl": "http://example.com",
                "duration": "PT00H11M27S",
                
                "uploadDate": "2022-07-30T13:12:05+00:00",
                "description": "SOMETEXT;",
                 "author" : "Klaus",        "interactionStatistic": [
                {
                      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                      "interactionType": "http://schema.org/WatchAction",
                      "userInteractionCount": "4,924,277"
                },
                {
                      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                      "interactionType": "http://schema.org/LikeAction",
                      "userInteractionCount": "10,469"
                 }
                ]
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` does not imply the input is empty. Try e.g. `json.loads('this is garbage')` and you'll get that error message too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't convert the tag to string with `str()`. Use `.text` property and then `json.loads`:

```py
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


s = """\
  <script type="application/ld+json">
            {
                "@context": "http://schema.org/",
                "@type": "DATA",
                "name": "Klaus ;",
                "embedUrl": "http://example.com",
                "duration": "PT00H11M27S",
                
                "uploadDate": "2022-07-30T13:12:05+00:00",
                "description": "SOMETEXT;",
                 "author" : "Klaus",        "interactionStatistic": [
                {
                      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                      "interactionType": "http://schema.org/WatchAction",
                      "userInteractionCount": "4,924,277"
                },
                {
                      "@type": "InteractionCounter",
                      "interactionType": "http://schema.org/LikeAction",
                      "userInteractionCount": "10,469"
                 }
                ]
            }
        </script>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(s, "html.parser")

data = soup.find("script", type="application/ld+json")
data = json.loads(data.text)

print(data)
```

Prints:

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "DATA",
    "name": "Klaus ;",
    "embedUrl": "http://example.com",
    "duration": "PT00H11M27S",
    "uploadDate": "2022-07-30T13:12:05+00:00",
    "description": "SOMETEXT;",
    "author": "Klaus",
    "interactionStatistic": [
        {
            "@type": "InteractionCounter",
            "interactionType": "http://schema.org/WatchAction",
            "userInteractionCount": "4,924,277",
        },
        {
            "@type": "InteractionCounter",
            "interactionType": "http://schema.org/LikeAction",
            "userInteractionCount": "10,469",
        },
    ],
}
```

Comment: When I do that and try to print it I get an empty line, which is why I used str().

Comment: @MaxFrost Try instead `data = json.loads(data.contents[0])`

Comment: When I use this and print "data" it shows the desired contents but then the replace function to replace " by ' doesn´t work anymore obviously :/

Comment: @MaxFrost You shouldn't replace `"` for `'`. Just parse the JSON with `json.loads` and use the data as normal python dictionary.

Comment: Got it :) But assuming I needed to replace it how would I do it ?